# How to know the configured size of the Chronicle Map?

Tags: chronicle-map

We use Chronicle Map as a persisted storage. As we have new data arriving all the time, we continue to put new data into the map. Thus we cannot predict the correct value for `net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder#entries(long)`. Chronicle 3 will not break when we put more data than expected, but will degrade performance. So we would like to recreate this map with new configuration from time to time.

Now it the real question: given a Chronicle Map file, how can we know which configuration was used for that file? Then we can compare it with actual amount of data (source of this knowledge is irrelevant here) and recreate a map if needed.

Answer (score 1):

`entries()` is a high-level config, that is not stored internally. What is stored internally is the number of segments, expected number of entries per segment, and the number of "chunks" allocated in the segment's entry space. They are configured via `ChronicleMapBuilder.actualSegments()`, `entriesPerSegment()` and `actualChunksPerSegmentTier()` respectively. However, there is no way at the moment to query the last two numbers from the created `ChronicleMap`, so it doesn't help much. (You can query the number of segments via `ChronicleMap.segments()`.)

You can contribute to [Chronicle-Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) by adding getters to `ChronicleMap` to expose those configurations. Or, you need to store the number of entries separately, e. g. in a file along with the ChronicleMap persisted file.